# Javascript - Disable all nested functions for some time after one function function has been executed

Tags: javascript

After a function has run I want to disable a whole set of functions can be executed again. I thought the most logical way would be to put them all together inside an overarching function (in this case `function run`) and disable that function for some time.

So for example in the code below, when function `exampleOne` is executed I want to disable the whole `run` function for X time before it can run again.

```
function run(){
  function exampleOne(){
    // Code
    sleep(1000);
  }

  function exampleTwo(){
    // Code
    sleep(1000);
  }
}
run();
```

Comment: You're looking for *throttling*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at underscore.js and especially the [throttle](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or [debounce](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce) functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your functions as variables then you can disable them by assigning an empty or error functions to these variables. Two functions (e.g. enable/disable) can be responsible to disable/enable the whole set of functions. and of course you can use `setTimeout` to manage the delay.

for example:

```
var exampleOne, exampleTwo;

function enable(){
    exampleOne = function(){       
        // do something

        disable();
        setTimeout(function() { enable(); }, 10000);
    }

    exampleTwo = function(){
        // do something

        disable();
        setTimeout(function() { enable(); }, 10000);
    }     
}

function disable(){
    exampleOne = function(){
        Alert("i'm sleep!")
    }

    exampleTwo = function(){
        // do nothing
    }     
} 

enable();
```